# Prestashop 1.7 Удаление поля в заказе

Tags: cms, prestashop

Доброго времени суток!
Бьюсь третий день, хочу убрать поле City(Город), т.к. за это поле будет отвечать поле Штата. Сделано это в связи с тем что не хочу городить огород по созданию таблицы городов, контролера для этой сущности, но даже если буду, не могу найти где можно редактировать это поле.
Обыскал в Теме все файлы связанные с checkout но не нашел. Кто знает подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно идти в `international->locations`, там править страну и убрать обязательное поле `city`.